# C++ Handling super basic errors how should I do this?

Tags: c++

```
double ctok(double c) // converts Celsius to Kelvin
{
    
    if (c <= -273.15)
    {
        cout << "Temp too low.";
        exit(1);
}
    else {
        double k = c + 273.15;
        return k;
    }   
        
}
int main()
{
    
        double c = 0;
        cin >> c; // retrieve temperature to input variable
        double k = ctok(c); // convecout << rt temperature
        cout << k << '/n'; // print out temperature
        
}
```

So if c is smaller or equal to -273.15 I want to basically stop the program and I wanna do all this in the ctok function so I just check with an if statement and then use exit() but  something here just seems off and I feel like this isn't a good way to handle it.. I've also heard using exit isn't really good but my only other idea is to handle this with exceptions:
So I add this function definition:

```
void  error(string s)
{
    throw runtime_error(s);
}
```

Then I can just do this:

```
double ctok(double c) // converts Celsius to Kelvin
{
    
    if (c <= -273.15)
    {
        error("Temp too low.");
}
    
    double k = c + 273.15;
    return k;
        
        
    
    
}
int main()
{
    try {
        double c = 0;
        cin >> c; // retrieve temperature to input variable
        double k = ctok(c); // convecout << rt temperature
        cout << k << '/n'; // print out temperature
    }
    catch (runtime_error a)
    {
        cout << a.what();
    }
}
```

But this also feels a little overkill  for handling such a simple error doesn't it? So I just wanna know is there like some good basic way to deal with such a basic error?

Comment: Maybe you could use `assert()` from the `cassert` library?

Comment: Your `ctok` function doesn't `throw` any exceptions, so there is nothing to catch.

Comment: Another technique is to pass a *status* variable (by reference) to indicate if the function succeeded or not (sounds like a `bool`) type.

Answer (score 0):

You could make ctok return bool and pass a pointer or reference to a variable and store the result:

bool ctok(double c, double *pr)

```
if( ! ctok( c, &k ) )
    cout << "error\n";
```

or simply ctok() should throw itself the exception instead of a function that do nothing more than a throw...

IMO, both are simple solutions for a simple program, even with your 'error()' function.